# How do I create a data pipeline to ferry data from DynamoDB to S3 and back again in Java?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

So basically I want to do what's in `AWS Console | DynamoDB | Export / Import | Export from DynamoDB **and** Import into DynamoDB`, except in Java (because I have to export multiple tables and eventually this will be on a monthly basis and part of a larger process, so I want it in a Java program).

I've been searching all morning, but [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LowLevelJavaWorkingWithTables.html) is all I can find for DynamoDB, a CLI interface. Is programming this possible?

Comment: Do you need to do a full table export each run? Why are you against using the built-in support with Data Pipelines? AWS manages exports and you don't have to deal with capacity, scheduling, or writing up a bunch of code for something that they already provide for you.

Comment: Yes, I need to do a full table export. There are only two options for the GUI: one-time export and daily export. I only need to run these exports once a month or once every three months. If I could restart the one-time pipelines, that would suffice, but I cannot see a way to do this.